# Add tableview as subview (if you have to inherit from UITableVC)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview

What I want is a tableview with an ad view on top for admob and pull to refresh. Right now i'm using the tableheaderview, but that scrolls and I need the ad to persist. viewforheader doesn't scroll, but gets rid of the standard headers that i need for the section headers. if im inheriting from a tableVC, is there anyway to override loadview to build a static view to hold an ad and then have the tableview below that? i've tried writing loadview and can get the ad, but when trying the tableview, i get "unable to restore selected frame" in the console.  i'm using culver's pull to refresh technique as its very simple to implement. i know a tableVC assumes the root view is a tableview so how can i get around that? every solution on the net says use a standard uiviewcontroller, but im stuck cause of the pull to refresh

this is in my loadview:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your view controller inherit from `UIViewController`, but continue to implement `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`.  Add your TableView as a sub-view of the UIViewController's built-in `view`, pointing to File's Owner for data source and delegate.  Make the table view less than 100% of the height, and have the ad as another view within the main view that makes it appear below/above the table.

[image]

source: I do this in my apps, and they are on the store.

Comment: I just can't get things to talk to each other correctly, can you help? I've got a PullRefreshVC and MyVC. PullRefreshVC has UIVC has superclass and MyVC has PullRefreshVC so that mine now inherits from UIVC like you wanted. In MyVC's viewdidload, PullRefreshVC's viewdidload is called by [super viewdidload]. In that, the view that shows when you pull down the tableview is setup and added as a subview. But it isn't showing when i try to add to self.tableview. if i do self.view, i see it. how can i get the superclass's self.tableview to be the tableview actually being shown on screen

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things you could try.

You could stop inheriting from `UITableViewController`, like everyone says.  If you're using Culver's `PullRefreshTableViewController`, adapt it to just subclass `UIViewController`.  You'll need to add back the `tableView` property, and adopt the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols if you do.

You could set the `contentInset` of the table view to leave room at the top, and define `scrollViewDidScroll:` in your controller to reposition the ad view appropriately on each scroll.  (`UITableView` subclasses `UIScrollView`, so it will call the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods if you define them.)

Comment: Thanks so much! I modified the PullToRefresh header to now inherit from UIViewController, added <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> then added a tableview property, but I see a bunch of warnings now. its complaining PullToRefresh doesn't implement some of the tableview methods like cellforrow but i have those in my own view controller.

i tried the content inset but it looks like clover's solution already uses that

Comment: You can just add a dummy `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to `PullRefreshTableViewController` to silence the warning, since you override it in your subclass anyway.

Comment: I just can't get things to talk to each other correctly, can you help? I've got a PullRefreshVC and MyVC. PullRefreshVC has UIVC as superclass and MyVC has PullRefreshVC so that mine now inherits from UIVC like you wanted. In MyVC's viewdidload, PullRefreshVC's viewdidload is called by [super viewdidload]. In that, the view that shows when you pull down the tableview is setup and added as a subview. But it isn't showing when i try to add to self.tableview. if i do self.view, i see it. how can i get the superclass's self.tableview to be the tableview actually being shown on screen